# Opening one corresponding related table in attribute form for selected feature in multipolygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, multi-polygon, relation, attribute-form

I have MultiPolygon A with 9 features, each feature should be described by one non-spatial attribute table with 10 - 500 features. I tried to create 9 relations like A-to-Table1, A-to_Table2 ...A-to-Table9. But when I select each feature on a map I can see the attribute form with all related tables for all 9 features.

Is it possible to observe only certain, corresponding related table for each selected feature?

I also considered creating custom HTML form with 9 buttons which open certain table but have no idea how to assign PyQGIS code to button tag in HTML form.

Update:
4 screenshots added. Room 18 may be either Multi Polygon or Polygon with 9 not-null features (pink colored on map). Each feature contains its own features described in non-spatial tables (for example table 1k content), and some attributes from non-spatial tables are aggregated in table Room 18. After establishing relations for all related tables I can see aggregated data and all relations in the form of each feature of Room18 (I made only 4 relations, for example, Room 18-to-1k content etc.). But in the form I would like to see aggregated data for each feature and only one certain relation.

[image: Room 18 may be either Multi Polygon or Polygon with 9 not-null features (pink colored on map).]
[image: Each feature contains its own features described in non-spatial tables (for example table 1k content),]
[image: and some attributes from non-spatial tables are aggregated in table Room 18.]
[image: After establishing relations for all related tables I can see aggregated data and all relations in the form of each feature of Room18 (I made only 4 relations, for example, Room 18-to-1k content etc.). But in the form I would like to see aggregated data for each feature and only one certain relation.]

Comment: I feel like this question could profit from a screenshot. Either you have one multi-polygon with 9 parts, or you have 9 features, or you have 90 to 4500 features.

Comment: Why did you create 9 table with 9 relation ? could you detail what you have exactly and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: So your spatial data stored in one table has several features where each feature should be related to different tables?

Comment: @Techie_Gus, right, but establishing relation is not essential, just I'd like to show aggregated and detailed information in one form.

Comment: @Erik, thank you, please see updated question.

Comment: @J.R thank you, please see updated question.